# Custom contrasts in lmer - reference group?

Tags: mixed-model, contrasts, categorical-encoding

I am a student working on data and am very confused about custom contrasts in a linear mixed model. I have tried it two ways.

### Method 1 (inverse contrast matrices):

```
contrast <- rbind (
  c1 = c(1/2, 1/2, -1), #Mediation (A and B) vs. Court
  c2 = c(-1, 1, 0) #A Mediation vs B Mediation
)

cMat <- ginv(contrast)

LMM4 <- lmerTest::lmer(
  formula = (yAppropriate ~ condition + sex + (1 | researchID)), 
  data = df_outcomes, contrasts = list(condition = cMat))
```

### Method 2 (CvSV and SvV is the c1 and c2 dummy code manually added into the data):

```
LMM4 <- lmerTest::lmer(
   formula = (yAppropriate.0 ~ CvSV + SvV + sex + (1 | researchID)), 
   data = df_outcomes)
```

We've heard from other experts that Method 1 is better for this analysis, however, I'm having trouble understanding the output for Method 1:

[image]

When I run Method 1, the values for condition 1 and condition 2 change if I change the reference group, even though that doesn't conceptually make much sense:

```
df_outcomes$condition <- relevel(df_outcomes$condition, ref = 'Court')
df_outcomes$condition <- relevel(df_outcomes$condition, ref = 'AMediation')
df_outcomes$condition <- relevel(df_outcomes$condition, ref = 'BMediation')
```

Thus, I am uncertain about the output. Furthermore, when I run Method 2, at times the **CvSV** output matches the condition 2 output from Method 1, and at times the **SvV** matches the condition 2 output from Method 1, and nothing matches the condition 1 output, regardless of the reference group I'm trying. Perhaps that's fine, but the inconsistent matches are concerning. Does the condition 1 row in the output mean Court vs Mediation? Or is it the condition 2 row in the output that is indicating the estimate for Court vs. Mediation?

I have also tried the following code to set the contrast time to `contr.treatment`, but it doesn't affect my output at all and I'm confused about what it is doing here:

```
df_outcomes$cMat <- c(df_outcomes$cMat, contr.treatment, base=3)
```

Comment: good question. For what it's worth, this problem is not specific to linear mixed models - it applies to any extension of linear models in R (ordinary linear model, GLM, etc.)

Comment: also ... I don't have time to answer right now, but think about the order of rows/columns in the contrast (or inverse-contrast) matrix: one dimension is the order of the parameters, the other is the *order of the groups (levels of the categorical variable)*. If you change the order of the levels, you have to make the corresponding change in the order of the columns of the inverse-contrast matrix ...

Comment: Thanks for the response! That's a good point about the order of the levels. Do you think when I'm changing the reference group, it's changing the order of the levels? Or that my rbind is comparing the wrong groups now since the order of my levels has shifted due to my reference group being changed?